# How to trigger (change) event manually in TypeScript?

Tags: html, angular, events

I have the the following select element:

```
<select (change)="onChange(start, end, break, project);" [acTotalStatus]="this.totalStatus"
        [acMonth]="this.date.month" [acYear]="this.date.year" [acCustomer]="this.selectedCustomerFromProject" 
        id="dailyEntryProject" class="form-control" name="project" [(ngModel)]="projectName" #project="ngModel" 
        tabIndex="0" required>
    <option value=" " disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option *ngFor="let project of projects" [ngValue]="project.name">{{project.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I have a two way binding `[(ngModel)]="projectName"` In one case im setting the `projectName` manually in typescript which does not trigger the `(change)` event. I would like to trigger it manually which i could not figure out how to do. The reason i dont call `onChange(start, end, break, project)` directly in typescript is because the parameters needed are defined within the html document.

I tried using changedetection, firing events, dispatching events etc. but couldnt find a way to trigger `(change)` manually yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are not calling onChange(params) directly as thet are defined in html. I have two points here:

1) You cannot ddefine anything in html.

2) The parameters inside onChange(params) must be already there in typescript. Only because they are present in ts file, you are able to access them in html.

And if these params are in ts file, you can use them anywhere in your entire application.

Comment: As you see in the code snippet above i use `#project="ngModel"` and use that defined `project` ngModel as a paramater. Its not defined in TypeScript.